# Generic Covariant class with upper type boundaries drawbacks

Tags: scala, generics, jvm, covariance

Scala suggests using the covariance solution [+T] for the variance problem in generic class, and when I dig into it I could produce two solutions, the thing is that each one of them has its own disadvantage.

Solution 1 - using upper type boundary both in the class header and in the method, for example.

```
class Animal(val name: String)
class Dog(override val name: String, val property: String) extends Animal(name)
class Puppy(override val name: String, override val property: String, val age: Int) extends Dog(name, property)
 
 
abstract class AnimalCage[+A <: Animal] {
  def head: A
  def tail: AnimalCage[A]
  def add[A <: Animal](animal: A): AnimalCage[Animal]
}
 
class RealCage[+A <: Animal](h: A, t: AnimalCage[A]) extends AnimalCage[A] {
  override def head: A = h
  override def tail: AnimalCage[A] = t
  override def add[A <: Animal](animal: A): AnimalCage[Animal] = new RealCage(animal, this)
}
 
object EmptyCage extends AnimalCage[Nothing] {
  override def head: Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException()
  override def tail: AnimalCage[Nothing] = throw new NoSuchElementException()
  override def add[A <: Animal](animal: A): AnimalCage[Animal] = new RealCage(animal, this)
}
 
  val dog1: Dog = new Dog("dog_1", "bark bark")
  val dogCage: RealCage[Dog] = new RealCage(dog1, EmptyCage)
  val puppy1: Puppy = new Puppy("puppy_1", "puppy bark", 5)
 
 
  val x: AnimalCage[Dog] = dogCage.add(puppy1) //error! must be Animal, could not be Dog!
```

pros - [Animal] is the higher super-class Cage can holds

cons - When I'm adding [Puppy] (sub-type of [Dog]) to a Cage of [Dog] I can't have Cage of [Dog] but rather Cage of [Animal].

solution 2 - using boundary only in method signature

```
abstract class AnyCage[+A] {
  def head: A
  def tail: AnyCage[A]
  def add[B >: A](animal: B): AnyCage[B]
}
 
class RealCage[+A](h: A, t: AnyCage[A]) extends AnyCage[A] {
  override def head: A = h
  override def tail: AnyCage[A] = t
  override def add[B >: A](animal: B): AnyCage[B] = new RealCage(animal, this)
}
 
object EmptyCage extends AnyCage[Nothing] {
  override def head: Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException()
  override def tail: AnyCage[Nothing] = throw new NoSuchElementException()
  override def add[B >: Nothing](animal: B): AnyCage[B] = new RealCage(animal, this)
}
 
  val dog1: Dog = new Dog("dog_2", "bark bark")
  val dogCage: AnyCage[Dog] = new RealCage(dog1, EmptyCage)
 
  val bug: LivingCreature = new LivingCreature("bug")
  val generalCage: AnyCage[Any] = dogCage.add(bug) // compiled but we lose all properties due to the fact the [Any] is lowest super-type.
```

pros - When I'm adding [Puppy] (sub-type of [Dog]) to a Cage of [Dog], I get Cage of [Dog] and not [Animal] like the previous solution.

cons - we don't have restrictions on AnyCage[+A] and we can potentially add any type, even if it's not related to Animal, and then the lower super-type would be [Any] which will cause us to lose all the properties of [Animal].

Therefore, the question is, if there is any way to combine the above two solution and do something like -

```
  abstract class AnimalCage[+A <: Animal] {
    def head: A
    def tail: AnimalCage[A]
    override def add[A <: B <: Animal](animal: B): AnimalCage[B] = new RealCage(animal, this)
  }
```

i.e, when we both can have restrictions on Cage (<: Animal) and also receive the lowest super-type (not [Animal] but [Dog]) in a case we want to add a [Puppy] to a Cage of [Dog].

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can combine both pretty easily, just use the right syntax. `override def add[B >: A <: Animal](animal: B): AnimalCage[B]`

Comment: Thanks! it works also with RealCage, but doesn't compiled with EmptyCage, what am I doing wrong? `class RealCage[+A <: Animal](h: A, t: AnimalCage[A]) extends AnimalCage[A] {
    override def add[B >: A <: Animal](animal: B): AnimalCage[B] = new RealCage(animal, this)
  }`
 and the EmptyCage - 
  `object EmptyCage extends AnimalCage[Nothing] {
    override def add[A <: Nothing](animal: A): AnimalCage[Animal] = new RealCage(animal, this)
  }`

Comment: This compiles as expected: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/6SLl6GkqSOGvjDo0BhjlHQ/1

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I will post the answer

Answer (score 1):

That'll do them both -

```
  class LivingCreature(val name: String)
  class Animal(val name: String)
  class Cat(override val name: String, val property: String) extends Animal(name)
  class Dog(override val name: String, val property: String) extends Animal(name)
  class Puppy(override val name: String, override val property: String, val age: Int) extends Dog(name, property)


  abstract class Cage[+A <: Animal] {
    // without explicitly point into my own class `<: Animal` in the class signature
    // the upper border would be [Any]
    def head: A
    def tail: Cage[A]
    def add[B >: A <: Animal](animal: B): Cage[B] = new RealCage(animal, this)
    // [A <: Animal] - means [Animal] is super-type of [A].
  }

  class RealCage[+A <: Animal](h: A, t: Cage[A]) extends Cage[A] {
    override def head: A = h
    override def tail: Cage[A] = t
    override def add[B >: A <: Animal](animal: B): Cage[B] = new RealCage(animal, this)
  }

  object EmptyCage extends Cage[Nothing] {
    override def head: Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException()
    override def tail: Cage[Nothing] = throw new NoSuchElementException()
    override def add[B >: Nothing <: Animal](animal: B): Cage[B] = new RealCage(animal, this)
  }

  val dog: Dog = new Dog("my_dog", "bark bark")
  val dogCage_1: Cage[Dog] = new RealCage(dog, EmptyCage)
  val puppy: Puppy = new Puppy("my_puppy", "puppy bark", 5)
  val dogCage_2:  Cage[Dog] = dogCage_1.add(puppy) // keeps Dog Cage

  val cat: Cat = new Cat("my_cat", "miau")
  val animalCage: Cage[Animal] = dogCage_2.add(cat)

  val bug: LivingCreature = new LivingCreature("my_bug")
  val x: Cage[LivingCreature] = animalCage.add(bug) // doesn't compile as expected
```

Thanks Luis

Comment: There is no need and no point in overriding the implementation of `add`

Comment: the key work `override` is indeed not necessary, but it helps to see that there is no redundancy with the method `def add`.

Comment: Actually, the keyword is necessary, because you are overriding an already implemented method. But, you are doing that just to give it the same implementation. `add` should only be defined in the parent trait a be `final`